# How to get lastviewed products programmatically?

Tags: product, product-attribute, products-view

I have a loop in a phtml file that search product for a particular attribute. I am beginner on PHP for Magento and I managed to make this foreach.

What I need now is to make a loop that shows the most recently viewed products programmatically to show in my custom phtml file.

Like this ::: http://image.prntscr.com/image/8111de5ee8a94957bc7bd815f756040c.png

**Anyone help me to make this loop?**

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    // add sorting to collection optional
    ->addAttributeToFilter('a_nao_pode_faltar_dtumpouco', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->load();

    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
```

This loop I made for custom product attribute! Now, I need a loop for lastviewed products.

Answer (score 1):

Marcos Vinicius,magento default have this feature.So there are no need of **doing any custom code**.

- The recent product's block class is
  `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed` and
- template phtml file is
  `app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/template/reports/product_viewed.phtml`.

**You need  phtml using below code:**

> `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')
>         ->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml();`

Or you can do via  layout report.xml at **app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/layout**  and  call thism block from layout

Comment: It's possible to edit **product_viewed.phtml** file to customize with my html/css?

Comment: yes ,sure.it possible..you can do